# Laravel log into custom log file

Tags: laravel, logging

I am reading in laravel documentation about logging but i can't find how to log something into my custom file. For example if i do this:

```
Log::info('I am logging something!');
```

or any other log message. This all goes into **laravel.log**

And what I want is to log that message for example into `/storage/logs/my_logs.log` file.

How to do this?

#### update

I don't want to overwrite the default log file....i want to have the laravel.log and also my own log file for my custom logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5.6 allows adding custom logging "channels" in config/logging.php.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#creating-custom-channels

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this package is useful for your purpose: 
https://github.com/Edujugon/laravel-log

It's really easy to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much this exactly what i am looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can add following lines in your `bootstrap/app.php` right before it returns the `$app`.

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function ($monolog) {
    $monolog->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(storage_path("logs/my_logs.log"), \Monolog\Logger::ERROR));
});
```

For more you can refer this post : [Advance Logging with Laravel and Monolog](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/advance-logging-with-laravel-and-monolog)
Or [Custom Monolog Handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#custom-monolog-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

In order to overwrite the default logging config, add the following in your **AppServiceProvider**:

```
public function register()
  $this->app->configureMonologUsing(function() {
    $this->app->log->useFiles($this->app->storagePath().'/logs/my_logs.log');
  });
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that i don't want to lose the default logging from laravel....that should stay intact....i just want to have my own logs in my own file.

Comment: Then you can't use the Log facade - the logger behind that just pushes all logs to the same location. And how should Laravel differentiate between YOUR logs and OTHER logs? Laravel uses Log facade internally as well.

Comment: If you want to easily identify YOUR logs, just add some unique string to the logged message and filter your logs by that string.

Comment: You could also create another facade that would use another instance of logger that would write to another location.